# visual studio 2005 to 2010 with boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

About a month a go I spent almost an entire week trying to figure out how to build the boost libraries for vs2005 and today I updated to vs2010.

Do I need to remove boost for vs 2005(I uninstalled vs2005) and go through the build process for 2010 or will it magically work and I can go take a nap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to rebuild Boost for the new version of Visual C++.

I don't believe anyone has released a binary distribution for Visual C++ 2010 yet.  [The BoostPro site](http://www.boostpro.com/download) would be the best place to get a binary distribution, and they don't have them yet.

It shouldn't be too difficult to build Boost if you follow the instructions in the [Boost Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).

Whether or not you take a nap is up to you.  If you build Boost from source, you may as well take one since the build is rather lengthy.

Comment: Hint, >6 Gb of disk space :| (boost build on msvc10)